# How to use Powershell expression in Powershell command?

Tags: powershell

On Linux I can run

```
docker run --volume $(pwd):/some_dir container_image
```

In Powershell, `$pwd` doesn't return the path string but instead returns some object. I learned that I can fetch the path by typing `$pwd.path`. But then this path has backslashes, which docker doesn't like. So I can type `$((pwd).path -replace "\\", "/")` to get the path with forward slashes.

But I now fail to understand how to use this variable in my original docker command.

On Windows, and in Powershell, this doesn't work:

```
docker run --volume $((pwd).path -replace "\\", "/"):/some_dir container_image
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In PowerShell for declaring any variable, we use $abc, not sure about docker.

Comment: @VinodkumarG `pwd` is an Alias for `Get-Location`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
docker run --volume "$((pwd).path -replace '\\', '/'):/some_dir" container_image
```

Here is the reason:

```
PS C:\> $((pwd).path):something
At line:1 char:14
+ $((pwd).path):something
+              ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ':something' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS C:\> "$((pwd).path):something"
C:\something
```

So, if you quote the whole path properly, it should work as you expect it. Because you are using `subexpression $()` outside a string, `':/somedir'` is not part of the path result. They are not automagically joined in linux (bash) shell.

Answer (score -1):

In Powershell, the `$((pwd).path -replace "\\", "/")` works well, so try to combine it all as a sting you pass as your full path:

```
docker run --volume ($((pwd).path -replace "\\", "/"))+":/some_dir" container_image
```

Full disclosure: I'm not famailiar with `docker` syntax, so can't promise this'll work, but worth a shot, right?